# How to work with multiple "instances" of the same form in a document

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

What is the easiest way to work with multiple instances of a duplicated form with duplicated controls.

```
<div id="divTest_Control1">
      <form id="frmBaseClass" >    
        <div id="divTest"></div>    
      </form>
</div>
<div id="divTest_Control2">    
      <form id="frmBaseClass">    
        <div id="divTest"></div>    
      </form>
</div>
```

The forms are being rendered as partial controls with @(Using AjaxBeginForm()...

Only one divTest_xxx will be visible at a time as I am hiding/showing the selected one opposed to reloading.

I have a handful of js functions as part of the partials being rendered so how to I relate to $this...$("#divTest").DoSomething will not always work as planned.

In reality there are many elements on each form and the visibility of each is being handled in generic js functions in the form itself. So, I ended up with a whole lot of elements with the same control ID.

I am fairly new to jquery and have made a rookie mistake. Any help is appreciated.
What is the best way to handle this type of situation?

Thanks

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Element IDs must be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: The best way to handle it would be to start with moving away from duplicate ID's and to classes. Next, instead of having js included for each duplicate form, have one js that will handle all of the duplicate forms.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have done something similar, only on a small scale. What if I started with a js that takes in a parent element. From there I could use var divTest=$("#"+parentDiv"+".divTest"); I am trying to find the best practices for what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to have multiple elements with the same id.  Change the 'shared' ids to classes.

e.g. Assuming you know that divTest_Control2 is the currently visible one then use a complex jquery selector to access the specific elements like:

$('#divTest_Control2 .divTest')...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You and Kevin B have similar answers. I just need to find a good white paper on sub classing controls.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get by this with a little work. The clashing Sub Views did cause a problem. So I put a property for report types views that Instructs to Always reload. This will buy me time until I can do it right.